# Removed all junk nodes in xml using php?

Tags: php

Removed ALL junk nodes in xml using php

This is the sample input for the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <!--comment1-->
    <elem>a</elem>
    <junk>b</junk>
    <elem>
        <!--comment2-->
        <junk>c<junk>d</junk></junk>
    </elem>
    <!--comment3-->
    <junk>e</junk>
</root>
```

This is the resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

    <elem>a</elem>

    <elem>


    </elem>


</root>
```

I look documents and applied like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('/root/') as $elem) {
    $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
}
```

for my case will remove all node "junk" and they will everywhere in xml document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Delete XML Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153697/php-delete-xml-element)

Comment: More convenient solution using XPath here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499694/delete-elements-in-xml

Comment: yes,but for me <junk> ,they are everywhere. i want to delete ALL elements that.

Comment: @python the accepted answer in my second link should work for you.  Something like `$entity->deleteNodes('//entity[type="junk"]');`

Comment: yes,but it used thid-parties,are there any where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//junk') as $elem)
```